# Solve $x^4 - 8x^3 + 21x^2 - 20x + 5 = 0$ given that the sum of two of its roots is $4$

Tags: polynomials

Here's what I tried:

Let the roots be $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, $a+b=4$. Then,

$$a + b + c + d = 8 \Longrightarrow 4 + c+ d = 8 \Longrightarrow a+b = c+d = 4$$
$$(a + b)(c + d) + ab + cd = 21$$
$$ab (c + d) + cd (a + b) = 20 \Longrightarrow 4ab + 4cd = 20 \Longrightarrow ab + cd = 5$$
$$abcd = 5$$

I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Not sure how to use the hint.  After checking (unsuccessfully) for rational roots, I'd try to factor into two quadratics (that works).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^4-8x^3+21x^2-20x+5=(x^2-4x+a)(x^2-4x+b)$

$\begin{cases}a+b+16=21 \\ -4a-4b=-20\\
ab=5 \end{cases}$

So $a+b=5$ and $ab=5$.

$a$, $b$ are the roots of $t^2-5t+5=0$.

Comment: The sum of the four roots is $8$. So if the sum of two of them is $4$, then the sum of the other two is also $4$.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have deleted my comment.(+1)

Answer (score 1):

Two of the roots sum to 4.  All 4 roots sum to 8.  This means that the other two roots must also sum to 4.

If this polynomial had rational roots, they would have to be in the set $\{\pm1,\pm5\}$

By what we have above we might try $x=-1, x = 5$ alas these do not work.

We could factor the polynomial like so:

$(x^2 - 4x + A)(x^2 -4x + B)\\
A+B = 5\\
AB = 5$

And solve for $A,B$

Or we might try
$(x -2 + a)(x-2-a)(x-2 + b)(x-2-b)$

Then substituting

$y = x-2\\x = y+2$

Into the original polynomial

$(y+2)^4 - 8(y+2)^3 + 21(y+2)^2 -20(y+2) + 5\\
y^4 - 3y^2+1\\
y^2 = \frac 32 \pm \sqrt 2\\
y = \pm \sqrt {\frac 32 \pm \sqrt 2}\\
x = 2\pm \sqrt {\frac 32 \pm \sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 0):

make the Ansatz $$x^4-8x^3+21x^2-20x+5=(x^2+Ax+B)(x^2+Cx+D)$$